# Reusing Repository Model in Service Model?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing a Web Api and am currently separating the Services Model from the Domain Model. But I am wondering if it is bad practice to reuse Repository Model in the Controller Model?

For example:

**Repository Models**

```
PersonRepositoryModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

PersonAddressRepositoryModel {
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
}
```

**Service Model**

```
PersonServiceModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonAddressRepositoryModel> { get; set; } // <-- Is this bad? Should I create a PersonAddressServiceModel?

}
```

My question is, is it always good practice to create Service Models even though the properties are exactly the same? Example is usage of PersonAddressRepositoryModel above where it will not have any different properties.

And then I would need to create an instance of the RepositoryModel if I want to use it in my repository like so:

```
IPersonRepository {
   public long AddNewPersonAddress(PersonAddressRepositoryModel newAddress);
}
```

Comment: Which architecture type have you used? I guess `Onion` is used.

Comment: Yes, I am using Onion Architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always a good practice to separate Domain Model from Service model.
The first rule of building web api is: never break a released api!

To never break this promise over time, having the two layer clearly separated is a must.

Over time usually your Domain Model changes, and if you have a separated Service Model you can handle the mismatch caused from changes under the hood instead of breaking the api.

This is a little extra effort you pay at start, but later you will be glad of that cost.

Comment: Thanks! I see it now, in the long run it will be more beneficial, even if there seems to be a 'repetition' of the properties. 

Can I ask how you name your Models in the Service and Domain model? To differentiate them?

Comment: @Water I usually name the classes in domain model as the entity they represent: like "Customer" and I name the class in service layer as entity name and the suffix "Dto": "CustomerDto". Dto like Data transfer object.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/OrderAggregate/Order.cs) (one of the Microsoft sample projects). There is a `Order` with some properties in Domain layer. If you inspect the properties you can see their `setters` are private, and they are accessible just in this class. The main reason for this design is controlling business in this class. It assist us in terms of maintenance.
So, to create an instance of `Order` and store it in a database, you need a different `DTO` or `Model` that would have same properties.